# Nginx Docker container can see other containers but not by exposed port

Tags: docker, nginx, networking

I am running two containers, Nginx and Hivemq.  In the nginx container, the below works:

```
root@14f03fa1193a:/# ping  broker1
PING broker1 (172.29.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from broker1.test (172.29.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.131 ms
64 bytes from broker1.test (172.29.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
```

However, I get a `Name or service not known` when I include the port for the other container.  The containers are run like this:

nginx:

```
docker run -d --name nginx --network test nginx
```

hivemqmq:

```
docker run -d -p 1883:1883 --name broker1 --network test hivemq/hivemq4:latest
```

`docker container inspect broker1` yields:

```
...
            "PublishAllPorts": false,

...
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "1883/tcp": {},
                "8000/tcp": {},
...
            "Ports": {
                "1883/tcp": [
                    {
```

Comment: Are you trying to ping on a specific port? If so, then use ```nmap``` command instead. Refer this: https://serverfault.com/a/309358

Comment: That did it -- thanks!